# MySQL GROUP BY a function and also return the function value in results

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am trying to group by Year Month DAy of a time stamp. I can manage to do it but I can't return the Year month day. The following sql does not work

```
SELECT 
count(ID), 
YEAR(user_registered) as reg_year, 
MONTH(users.user_registered) as reg_month, 
DAYOFMONTH(users.user_registered) as reg_day
FROM users
WHERE 
  user_registered > '2020-11-31' 
group by 
  YEAR(users.user_registered), 
  MONTH(users.user_registered), 
  DAYOFMONTH(users.user_registered);
```

Comment: Your query works: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w96jT7NPTYA4DJ45Z7vtCm/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use the alias in the group by.

```
SELECT 
count(`ID`), 
YEAR(user_registered) as reg_year, 
MONTH(`user_registered`) as reg_month, 
DAYOFMONTH(`user_registered`) as reg_day
FROM `sf_users` 
WHERE 
  user_registered > '2020-11-31' 
group by 
  reg_year, 
  reg_month, 
  reg_day;
```

Comment: 11-31 was a great day